# É possível realizar um Update dessa forma?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Eu possuo duas tabelas, a Tabela `Impressoras` é onde é armazenado os dados do equipamento, como modelo, patrimônio, etc. E tenho a tabela `Impressora Local` onde fica armazenado o local onde a impressora está, o cliente onde ela está alocada atualmente.

Minha tabela `Impressoras` possui uma coluna `codigoempresa` onde quando a impressora e cadastrada é colocada a empresa inicial para onde ela vai, e nessa tabela `Impressora Local` fica armazenado um histórico de onde a impressora passou, por esse motivo nessa tabela `Impressora Local` a empresa (código da empresa) esta sempre atualizado, mas na tabela `Impressoras` não.

Consegui resolver essa questão de manter esse dado atualizado na tabela `Impressora` também criando uma *Funtion* no banco que sempre que um registro for alterado ou adicionado na tabela `Impressora Local` o dado (código empresa) seja atualizado automaticamente. Isso funciona normalmente.

Porém a primeira vez, eu terei que atualizar esses dados no braço, por esse motivo tentei fazer um comando de Update do seguinte modo:

```
UPDATE public.impressoras
    SET codigoempresa=(select codigoempresa from public.impressoralocal)
    WHERE public.impressoras.codigo = (select codigoimpressora from public.impressoralocal);
```

Porém o seguinte erro me é retornado:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
********** Error **********

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

Minha dúvida é, é possível atualizar assim essa tabela `Impressoras`, ou serei obrigado a atualizar linha por linha

**Observação:** Esse banco é um legado por esse motivo estou tendo que adotar tal medida

Tabela Impressoras:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Impressora Loca:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloque a estrutura das tabelas por favor, e qual a query que você executa na "primeira vez"

Comment: @RovannLinhalis como assim primeira vez?

Comment: você que disse: "Porém a primeira vez, eu terei que atualizar esses dados no braço", isso seria no INSERT ? qual código que você executa ?

Comment: Ah sim, é que como hoje em dia a tabela `Impressoras` está com o `codigoempresa` desatualizado eu terei que fazer o primeiro comando Update na mão, hoje eu estou alterando assim: `UPDATE public.impressoras
 SET codigoempresa = 20 where
    codigoimpressora in (4,5,6)`. Mas são muitas impressoras por isso gostaria de saber se há uma forma mais eficaz

Comment: entendi, se puder coloca a estrutura das tabelas que ajuda bastante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconsiderando a questão de que não seria necessário a coluna `codigoempresa` no cadastro de impressoras, uma vez que já tem todo o histórico na outra tabela:

Para o problema de várias linhas, você pode utilizar um `LIMIT 1` ou `MAX([idHistorico])`

Para o seu update que irá executar da primeira vez, manualmente, você pode fazer assim: [aguardando estrutura das tabelas para confirmar os campos]

```
Update impressoras set 
    codigoempresa = (
                     Select 
                         x.codigoempresa 
                     from impressoralocal x 
                     where x.codigoimpressora = impressoras.codigo 
                     order by x.codigo desc limit 1);
```

> Esse código irá atualizar todos os registros em `impressoras`

Comment: Perfeito, era isso que eu precisava, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: por nada, disponha =]

Answer (score 0):

As subqueries dentro do seu `SET` e `WHERE` retornam mais de um valor porque você não filtra qual especificamente está procurando.

Entenda:

```
UPDATE public.impressoras
    SET codigoempresa=(select codigoempresa from public.impressoralocal WHERE public.nomeimpressora = 'Minha impressora')
    WHERE public.impressoras.codigo = (select codigoimpressora from public.impressoralocal WHERE public.nomeimpressora = 'Minha impressora');
```

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: ainda assim irá retonar mais de um registro na subquery, porque impressoralocal grava um histórico das impressoras, podendo ter mais de um registro com o mesmo 'nomeimpressora'

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, testei a do @RovannLinhalis e funcionou perfeitamente para minha necessidade